# Wireless XP users don't get their home folder mapped

Tags: active-directory, wifi

We're using Windows XP and Active Directory, we have a number of laptops that have a excellent connection to the wireless network, the logon script runs and maps the required drives etc, all appears fine apart from the Home Folder isn't mapped, we rely on the home folder mapping to be done by AD when the user logs on we don't map this with the logon script.

The problem is the home folder doesn't get mapped when using wireless, plug an ethernet cable in and the home folder is mapped. What could be causing this? Anyone and ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps an obvious point, but have you verified that SMB-based communication between the clients and the server hosting the "home folder" shares functions properly via the wireless network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have Wireless Zero Config setup to be able to authenticate before the user is completely logged in.  You need to have the machine able to connect to wireless without user interaction in order to authenticate against AD and now cached credentials as squillman said.

[How to enable computer-only authentication for a 802.1X-based network in Windows Vista, in Windows Server 2008, and in Windows XP Service Pack 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929847)

Answer (score 1):

When is it that the wireless connection is established, before or after login?  It sounds like the machine is logging in (with cached credentials) prior to the network connection being established.  This being the case, there would be no network connection for use to map the drive.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it would help to put a sleep-statement at the beginning of you the logon scripts. Or a more elegant way would be to check (via ping) the connectivity to your fileserver and retry as long as it is NOT reachable ...

Comment: He said that he's not using a script to "map" the "home folder". He's relying on the "legacy" home directory functionality for that. That aside, using "sleep statements" in scripts rather than getting at the root cause is poor form.